# How to roll back a transaction on Android?

Tags: java, android

Here is the standard idiom for transactions:

```
   db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     ...
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

I want to add a catch block, and I want to issue a rollback. Is it possible, and at all do I need it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need it.

If there is an exception in the `...` in your above code, the code you already have will roll back the transaction. The `finally {}` block is executed after the `catch() {}` block.

Comment: What if your own code gets an exception? Then half of what you intended to do will be committed. Is there an explicit rollback?

Comment: "What if your own code gets an exception?" -- that is what is indicated by the `...` in the above code snippet. "Then half of what you intended to do will be committed." -- no, it won't. "Is there an explicit rollback?" -- no, and you don't need one.

Comment: Oh, i didn't see the `db.setTransactionSuccessful();`