# How can we Rollback a transaction?

Tags: android

Is there any direct method in android to Rollback a transaction?? If no then how can we Rollback a Transaction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to roll back a transaction on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401033/how-to-roll-back-a-transaction-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is handled automatically; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401033/how-to-roll-back-a-transaction-on-android) thread for details.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using SQLite, simply use the standard SQL transaction syntax

```
START TRANSACTION
// SQL Here
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
// or
END TRANSACTION
```